# Subtracting two datetimes from each other and returning in HH:MM:SS in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime

I have two date-time strings that I wish to subtract from each other and want to return a answer in 
the `HH:MM:SS` format using python 2.7. For Example I have `"2019-01-22 10:46:34"` and `"2019-01-22 10:30:34"` and want it to return something like this `00:16:00`. I have tried converting the times to integers but can't seem to convert back. I have also tried the datetime module. Below is a rudimentary example of something I tried that I wish to convert into a function.

```
from datetime import datetime
a = "2019-01-22 10:46:34"
b = "2019-01-22 10:30:25"
c = a-b
print(datetime.time(c, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I have been working on this problem for a few days so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) Object.

With that you can get the difference of two `datetime` Objects in Seconds and then you can calc the Minutes Hours etc.

Example you have two `datetime` objects `a` and `b`, `c` will be the `timedelta` object:

```
import datetime 

# datetime object (year, month, day, hour, minute, second) 
a = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-22 10:46:34", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
b = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-22 10:30:25", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# returns timedelta object 
c = a-b  
print('Difference: ', c) 

# return (minutes, seconds) 
minutes = divmod(c.seconds, 60)  
print('Difference in minutes: ', minutes[0], 'minutes', 
                                 minutes[1], 'seconds')
```

**EDIT:** `divmod()` is used to get batter result in terms of minutes and seconds, but you could also just write

```
minutes = c.seconds / 60
print('Difference in minutes: ', minutes)
```

Output: `Difference in minutes: 16 minutes 9 seconds`

Comment: Thanks, would this mean I would have to break up the string into individual components as seen in the tuple above?